# Extract code from PHP function and insert in earlier function

Tags: php, function, include, head

Is it possible to call a function in PHP that contains code meant for the head of a document that can be inserted into the head.

eg.

```
<head>
<title>PHP Test</title>

<?php extra_data();?>

</head>

<body>

<?php new_function();?>

</body>
```

So when `new_function()` is called it outputs some code but also contains so extra info for the head such as a stylesheet that can be added to the `extra_data()` function in the head at the top.

Since its all being executed on the server anyway is this possible?

Comment: Did I misunderstand your question? You want `new_function()` to affect `extra_data()` but AFTER `extra_data()` is executed? `PHP` is sequential...

Comment: Learn MVC, then you wont need todo all this shenanigans...

Answer (score 0):

You can define `extra_data()` like so:

```
function extra_data(){
  $new_function_data = new_function();
  switch($new_function_data['extra']){
    case 1:
       echo '<link href="extra1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">';
       break;
    case 2:
       echo '<link href="extra2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">';
       break;
  }
}
```

You can define `new_function()` like so:

```
function new_function(){
  //Add logic to determine what data should be returned
  $data['normal'] = 'Normal data to output';
  $data['extra'] = 'Extra data for extra_data()';
  return $data;
}
```

and change your php to

```
<?php $new_function_data = new_function(); echo $new_function_data['normal']; ?>
```

Comment: The content of extra_data() is being defined by new_function() though which is called later. Think of it as new_function() including a gallery based on the users location and then sending the stylesheet of that gallery to extra_data(); extra_data() won't know the stylesheet in question until new_function() has been called.

Comment: If you can have `new_function()` return what `extra_data()` needs to know you can call `new_function()` inside `extra_data()`

Comment: updated answer. I think I know what you are after now.